# Managing several windows of the same Workbook using VBA on Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I want to see side by side 3 instances of the same workbook, open in 3 different tabs, in a tiled style view. So I have this code to open 2 other windows of the same workbook and then arrange them in a tiled way

```
ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).NewWindow
ActiveWorkbook.Windows(2).NewWindow

Application.Windows.Arrange ArrangeStyle:=xlArrangeStyleTiled
```

So what I get is this:

[image]

But now who do I go about to access the different windows that I have open. For instance, how do I change the ActiveSheet in window 2?

I have tried

```
ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).Sheets("2017").Activate
```

But it throws the error "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: your own code should help, ? ActiveWorkbook.Windows(x).ActiveCell.Address, use intellisense on what you know, or use the object browser, locals window.

Comment: Simply use the macro recorder here.

Comment: Activate the window and the refer to the sheet by name as normal.

Answer (score 0):

your own code should help, ? `ActiveWorkbook.Windows(x).ActiveCell.Address`, use intellisense on what you know, or use the object browser, locals window.

Answer (score 0):

I've started working on this problem, but don't have a complete solution yet.

From what I understand, WINDOWS(1) always refers to the active window. It doesn't refer to the same window each time. I've been trying to grab each window by declaring it as a variable.

I use

DIM MainWindow, SecondWindow As Window

Set Mainwindow = ThisWorkbook.Windows(1)

Set SecondWindow = ThisWorkbook.NewWindow

That said, this isn't a complete solution. I too am struggling to select a worksheet in a given window. Hope this stepping stone helps.